# wrong response format django-rest-framework

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, react-redux

iam creating a music web app using react-redux and django and i have function that returns single playlist it returns html response instead of json knowing that its working right when the two apps are seperated but when iam using django routs as my main routs and react like an interface only using this line:

```
urlpatterns += re_path(r'', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
```

here is my function

```
**django**
class getplaylist(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer]
    def get(self,request):
        id=request.META.get('HTTP_ID',None)
        plst=playlist.objects.get(id=id)
        return Response(plst)



**react**
export const getPlaylist=(id)=>{
    return dispatch=>{
        dispatch(getPlaylistStart())
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/songs/getplaylist/',{headers:{ 'id':id}})
        .then(res=>{
            console.log(res);
            dispatch(getPlaylistSuccess(res.data))
        })
    }
}
```

and this is the response

```
playlist(pin):"<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png"/><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/><title>Songs App</title><link href="/static/css/2.3327982c.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"><link href="/static/css/main.18cf81d6.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div><script>!function(e){function r(r){for(var n,f,l=r[0],i=r[1],a=r[2],c=0,s=[];c<l.length;c++)f=l[c],Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,f)&&o[f]&&s.push(o[f][0]),o[f]=0;for(n in i)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(i,n)&&(e[n]=i[n]);for(p&&p(r);s.length;)s.shift()();return u.push.apply(u,a||[]),t()}function t(){for(var e,r=0;r<u.length;r++){for(var t=u[r],n=!0,l=1;l<t.length;l++){var i=t[l];0!==o[i]&&(n=!1)}n&&(u.splice(r--,1),e=f(f.s=t[0]))}return e}var n={},o={1:0},u=[];function f(r){if(n[r])return n[r].exports;var t=n[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[r].call(t.exports,t,t.exports,f),t.l=!0,t.exports}f.m=e,f.c=n,f.d=function(e,r,t){f.o(e,r)||Object.defineProperty(e,r,{enumerable:!0,get:t})},f.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},f.t=function(e,r){if(1&r&&(e=f(e)),8&r)return e;if(4&r&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var t=Object.create(null);if(f.r(t),Object.defineProperty(t,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&r&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var n in e)f.d(t,n,function(r){return e[r]}.bind(null,n));return t},f.n=function(e){var r=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return f.d(r,"a",r),r},f.o=function(e,r){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,r)},f.p="/";var l=this.webpackJsonpfrontend=this.webpackJsonpfrontend||[],i=l.push.bind(l);l.push=r,l=l.slice();for(var a=0;a<l.length;a++)r(l[a]);var p=i;t()}([])</script><script src="/static/js/2.25085612.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.dc42ca8e.chunk.js"></script></body></html>"
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the trailing slash? `http://127.0.0.1:8000/songs/getplaylist`

Comment: you are right that was the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your problem not too clear yet like how you using reactJS with django.

If your ReactJS and Django app running together in same server, then you have to something in url pattern with regex.

Also test his url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/songs/getplaylist/` in your browser instead of ajax request.

If you see your endpoint well, that is mean your url/router pattern is good to go. if not, please update your route to with regex.